# Need help to grouping php arrays to make it better

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all, my grouping is working but I feel it is dirty. Need someone to make it looks 
clean and better.
I have following foreach

```
$data['new_array'] = array();  //I have to use $data['new_array'] because I need to pass it to template.
foreach ($get_topics as $topic) {
    //Is that possible to make these 4 lines shorter?
    $data['new_array'][$topic['tid']]['tid'] = $topic['tid'];   
    $data['new_array'][$topic['tid']]['title'] = $topic['title'];
    $data['new_array'][$topic['tid']]['yes'] = $topic['yes'];
    $data['new_array'][$topic['tid']]['no'] = $topic['no'];

    //The belows are subarray grouping, it actually works but I need better solutions
    //$new_array[$topic['tid']]['vid'][$topic['vid']][] = $topic['vid'];
    //$new_array[$topic['tid']]['vid'][$topic['vid']][] = $topic['yesno'];
}
```

Comment: `$data['new_array'][$topic['tid']] = $topic;`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even try to make it shorter, but here's your code in a good looking version.

```
$data['new_array'] = array();

foreach ($get_topics as $topic) {
    $data['new_array'][$topic['tid']] = array(
        'tid' => $topic['tid'],
        'title' => $topic['title'],
        'yes' => $topic['yes'],
        'no' => $topic['no']
    );
}
```

Not sure what type is $topic['tid'] but you should be careful when using non-consecutive numbers as array keys.

Comment: Can you take a look this arrays?   I posted the original from query, and edited arrays which i want it to be.
I still no idea how to group and access to each array.
http://codepad.org/5FxBBrPL

Comment: You say in your post "... my grouping is working but I feel it is dirty..." I suggested how to make it look cleaner as this seemed to be your only problem. Based on your code posted on codepad I don't get what you expect. What's __tid__ and __vid__? and how are they supposed to be related to each other?

Comment: Yes, it working, but I don't know how to access to them. No idea how to foreach and loop [vid] arrays

Comment: tid is topic id and vid is comment id.  Check the codepad again. I followed your codes and got the arrays i want but how can i foreach to loop them?

Comment: Now you ask question completely unrelated to your initial post. Well, you should use separate foreach loops for every level of nested arrays. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for some examples